# implementing font awesome in json

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to show some font awesome icons. I have some text that is written in json through a rakefile, and i am trying to incorporate a font awesome icon within the text, but having troubles because the text is in json, I was wondering if someone could take a quick look at it and help me out.  The icon is not appearing, however within the dev tools, there is extra blank space where it should be appearing.

I am using haml, with angular on the front end. I don't think I am needed to show the controller for this. I also, did sub out what i really have with deez nuts.

The area in my rakefile is so

```
{
   "partial":"message",
   "params":{
      "primary": true,
      "icon": "<i class='fa fa-odnoklassniki'></i>",
      "body":" With Deez Nuts as your president, you can have the full assurance of knowing that your country will be awesome   "
   }
},
```

and the haml file that should render this is here

```
%div{ 'ng-if' => 'option.params.primary' && 'option.params.icon'}
    %div{ 'ng-include' => "'/assets/ng/features/politicians/satire/presidents.html'" }
```

Comment: I bet Deez Nuts would be able to figure this one out. But srsly, are you getting any errors in the console? Interpreting HTML via angular wont output the tags unless you use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` I am not familiar with haml to give you a full answer

Answer (score 1):

Your html is probably stripped by angular. Inspect the output to make sure. You can add this filter to your app to render trusted html:

```
.filter('trustedHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}])
```

and than you can apply it to any data: `{{foo | trustedHtml}}`